# dot slash and directory level when using require

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var something = require('./utils');
```

What vale does the `./`add? Why not just `require('utils');`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you specify `require('./utils')` nodejs loads utils.js file present in the same directory.

In case of `require('utils')` nodejs either loads its core module (if it is one) or searches it in node_modules directory. It it finds one there, it loads it or goes to its parent directory and searches again in node_modules until it reaches root directory. If still not found it throws 'module not found' error.

Comment: so it's a `special' snytax for nodejs?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by 'special' syntax ? `require('moduleName')` is how you require nodejs core or npm installed module. `require('filepath')` is how you require functions/variables you had exported in your file.

Comment: Not a special syntax @NicholeA.Miler, but rather being explicit and telling nodejs exactly what you want. `./` tells nodejs that it shall load it from the current directory, and nowhere else.